# Django: Filter database query in template

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I think the answer is simple but I can't figure it out. So I have three models: host, project and a model that relates those two. In my template I have two 'select' inputs, one for the host and one for the project. What I want to do is show only the projects that are related to the host that is currently selected(the relations are described in the third model). Perhaps there is a better way to do this in the `views.py` file than in the html page.

Code:

```
class Projetos(models.Model):
    nomeAlias = models.CharField("Nome do Projeto",max_length=50, default='Personalizado')
    nome = models.CharField("Nome do Projeto(Artifactory)",max_length=50, primary_key=True)
    repositorio = models.CharField("Repositório do Projeto", max_length=150)
    remote_war = models.CharField("Nome do WAR do projeto",max_length=150)

class Maquina(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField("Nome da Máquina",max_length=20) 
    endereco = models.CharField("Endereço da Máquina",max_length=300, primary_key=True)

class RelMaquinaProjeto(models.Model):
    maquina = models.ForeignKey(Maquina, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='relacoes',verbose_name="Nome da Máquina")
    projeto = models.ForeignKey(Projetos, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='projetos_em',verbose_name="Nome do Projeto")
    contexto = models.CharField("Contexto",max_length=20)
```

Comment: Your code please !!!

Comment: Just updated with my code

Comment: where is your host models ?

Comment: which version of django  you use ?

Comment: The host model is the `class Maquina`. I'm using django 2.1

Comment: You have forgoten to add related_name in your RelMaquinaProjeto model in foreignkey field ... You must add it, update your code post and wait my answer ...

Comment: Did a quick research, but I'm not sure what `related_name` really does, but added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `Projetos` and `Maquina` models are related via a many to many relationship. Since you have already defined the model for this relationship , you can make it a through model and define the field in one of the tables like below.

Also refer [the Django docs for many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)

```
class Projetos(models.Model): 
   nomeAlias = models.CharField("Nome do Projeto",max_length=50, 
   default='Personalizado')
   nome = models.CharField("Nome do Projeto(Artifactory)",max_length=50, 
   primary_key=True)
   repositorio = models.CharField("Repositório do Projeto", max_length=150)
   remote_war = models.CharField("Nome do WAR do projeto",max_length=150)

class Maquina(models.Model):
   nome = models.CharField("Nome da Máquina",max_length=20) 
   endereco = models.CharField("Endereço da Máquina",max_length=300, 
   primary_key=True)
   projetos = models.ManyToManyField(Projetos, through='RelMaquinaProjeto', related_name='maquinas')

class RelMaquinaProjeto(models.Model):
   maquina = models.ForeignKey(Maquina, 
   on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Nome da Máquina")
   projeto = models.ForeignKey(Projetos, 
   on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Nome do Projeto")
   contexto = models.CharField("Contexto",max_length=20)
```

Now to select all the projects for a host object, you can do the following.

```
maquina.projetos.all()
```

To select all hosts for a project object, you could also do

```
projeto.maquinas.all()
```

or you could use the through model to filter as required

```
#retrieve all maquina-projetos for a given maquina

models.RelMaquinaProjeto.objects.filter(maquina=maquina)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you build the relation using a `models.ManyToManyField()` as described [in the Django docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships), then Django knows about the kind of relation between the two Models, and will display the "two-step select" in the *Admin*.

To write your own "two-step select", you will need JavaScript on the client to change the values in the second select box. Depending on how much data you have, you could just send all the options for all "second select boxes" to the client on initial load.

Or (and more likely) you will need to fetch the data from the server when the user selects a different "first option". To do that, there is no "plug-in" widget, as far as I know.